# Change default line width in scikitplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using scikitplot library for some specific plots, I'm using the code from the example:

```
import scikitplot as skplt
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr = lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_probas = lr.predict_proba(X_test)
skplt.metrics.plot_lift_curve(y_test, y_probas)
plt.show()
```

Which generates the following plot:

[image]

My issue with this plot is that the lines are too width, and does not seems to be a parameter to change that in the class:

```
scikitplot.metrics.plot_lift_curve(y_true, y_probas, title='Lift Curve', ax=None, figsize=None, title_fontsize='large', text_fontsize='medium')
```

I tried this:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 1.0
```

But the result is not changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the linewidth is [hardcoded in `plot_lift_curve`](https://github.com/reiinakano/scikit-plot/blob/d05d83e66319dcb5390769628f9a529cf7cc238f/scikitplot/metrics.py#L1211). In this case, changing `rcParams` won't have any effect since it only provides default values and are superseded by hardcoded values;

A possible solution is to change the properties of the `Line2D` objects after the fact:

```
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr = lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_probas = lr.predict_proba(X_test)
ax = skplt.metrics.plot_lift_curve(y_test, y_probas)
for l in ax.lines:
    l.set_lw(0.5)
plt.show()
```

if you want to change only certain lines, you can access them using e.g. `ax.lines[0].set_lw(1.0)`